# Conga Master Field to Set not working

Tags: conga, conga-composer

I'm trying to automatically set some account fields in a Conga Composer solution, but they don't seem to be working.

Here's the section of my solution code:

```
&MFTS0=Last_Acknowledge_Run__c
&MFTSValue0=TODAY
&MFTS1=EFO_Alerts__c
&MFTSValue1="TODAY"
&UF0=1
```

Last_Acknowledge_Run__c -> this is a date field
EFO_Alerts__c -> this is a text field

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation with Conga, MFTS only works on the object you're running conga against.  You can't set a field on the parent object.

e.g. the case above was running Conga against an opportunity object, but trying to set the field on the parent account object.  Conga can't do this.